# I am logo designer a doubt to design a trident logo

Tags: sin

I am logo designer and i want to brand my business with a trident symbol and my business name is starting with letter W so i thought to make it more creative way is that possible wether i can design it ?

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model I strongly suggest you to take the [tour] and check our [help]. One question why do you think it should be sinful to design such a logo?